# Mysql, Multiple Left Join - 3 Tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some issues with multiple joins in MysQL
I have 3 tables:

- cms_data_company
- cms_data_company_categories
- cms_datasrc_category

Sample records from: **cms_data_company**:

```
+----+-----------+------------+
| id | name      | address    |
+----+-----------+------------+
| 1  | Name1     | Samplestr1 |
+----+-----------+------------+
| 2  | Name2     | Samplestr2 |
+----+-----------+------------+
| 3  | Name3     | Samplestr3 |
+----+-----------+------------+
```

Sample records from: **cms_data_company_categories** ( It contains Company_id field and category_id ) Point is that there is serveral records for one company_id )

```
+----+-----------+------------+
| id | company_id| category_id|
+----+-----------+------------+
| 1  | 2         | 14         |
+----+-----------+------------+
| 2  | 2         | 11         |
+----+-----------+------------+
| 3  | 1         | 15         |
+----+-----------+------------+
```

Sample records from: **cms_datasrc_category** ( Here is a issue that i need only that rows where:

```
 datasrc = 1 AND parent = 0

+----+-----------+------------+-----------+
| id | datasrc   | parent     |name       |
+----+-----------+------------+-----------+
| 1  | 1         | 0          |category1  |
+----+-----------+------------+-----------+
| 2  | 2         | 0          |category2  |
+----+-----------+------------+-----------+
| 3  | 3         | 5          |category3  |
+----+-----------+------------+-----------+
```

What i would like to recive is that:

**All fields** from cms_data_company and field **name** from cms_datasrc_company

I need to join it as follows:

1. **id** from cms_data_company match with **company_id** from cms_data_company_categories
2. Then matched **category_id** from
   cms_data_company_categories with **ID** from cms_datasrc_category (only these records where datasrc=0 and parent=0)
3. Return name as new column with all field from cms_data_company

I think I could make it messy, but my MySQL statement is as follows:

```
select * ,cms_datasrc_category.name_en
from cms_data_company
LEFT JOIN cms_data_company_categories.company_id
ON cms_data_company.id = cms_data_company_categories.company_id 
LEFT JOIN cms_datasrc_category
ON cms_data_company_categories.category_id = cms_datasrc_category.id
WHERE cms_datasrc_category.datasrc = 1 AND cms_datasrc_category.parent = 0
```

It seems It is working somehow but, there is only records from cms_data_company where query can find something. I would like to change my statemat to show NULLs when There is no matching fields.

It is because WHERE applies to all Query ?

Answer (score 3):

When you use `left join`s, conditions on all but the first table should be in the `on` clauses:

```
SELECT *, cdc.name_en
FROM cms_data_company dc LEFT JOIN
     cms_data_company_categories.company_id c
     ON dc.id = c.company_id LEFT JOIN
     cms_datasrc_category cdc
     ON c.category_id = cdc.id AND
        cdc.datasrc = 1 AND cdc.parent = 0;
```

Notes:

- Table aliases make a query easier to write and to read.
- You should use table aliases for all column references, when your query has more than one table.
- The `select *` already selects all columns from all tables.  There is no need to include another column.  Or, better yet, list the columns you really need.
- The filtering conditions are on the last table, so they are now in the `on` clause.

Comment: Thank You for fast reply I've made an mistake on: LEFT JOIN cms_data_company_categories.company_id It should be: LEFT JOIN cms_data_company_categories But It is no problem now. Now there is issue with this: cms_data_company_categories contains column company_id where there is serveral categories_id for one company_id .
Now it returns all of records it founds.

I would like to return, that categories_id which in table cms_datasrc_category
Has datasrc = 1 AND parent = 0